# iOS C# Development with ViewControllers

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, viewcontroller

I am aware this has been probably answered in several places but I cannot find one solution that has so far worked. Currently I am working with Xamarin.iOS. So I have three empty ViewControllers in my .storyboard file. When the app loads, in the ViewDidLoad() I create two buttons, a label and and image. So now, in my button event:

```
male.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
        //save settings for male
        //
        //go to next screen
    };
```

I want to load the next ViewController, with the class of view_setup_3 and the name of Setup3.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current view controller is embedded inside a `UINavigationController` you can use the `NavigationController` property to push your new view controller.

```
male.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
        //save settings for male
        //
        //go to next screen
        NavigationController.PushViewController(Setup3);
    };
```

Use `NavigationController.PushViewController(new view_setup_3());` if you need to create a new instance.

If you're using storyboards you can create a segue by opening your storyboard and holding the ctrl-key as you drag with the left mouse button from your button to the destination view controller. Then select the segue and give it a unique identifier.
Now you can use the segue identifier to display the view controller.

```
male.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
        //save settings for male
        //
        //go to next screen
        PerformSegue("segueIdentifier", this); // Replace "segueIdentifer" with your unique identifier.
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using storyboards and just want to link to another viewcontroller without any other logic, you'd be better off using Segues: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_storyboards/